# My C++ functions with Rcpp::List inputs are very slow

Tags: r, rcpp

While C++ and specifically the Rcpp package have been tremendously helpful to me in speeding up my codes, I noticed that my C++ functions which have a list or data frame input argument(arguments of the form Rcpp::DataFrame and Rcpp::List) are very slower compared to my other C++ functions. I wrote a sample code and I wanted to ask for tricks that can make my code faster:

First, let's simulate a List in R that contains two Lists inside of it. Consider **myList** as a list that includes two lists - measure1 and measure2. measure1 and measure2 are lists themselves each include vectors of measurements for  subjects. Here is the R code:

```
lappend <- function(lst, ...){
  lst <- c(lst, list(...))
return(lst)
}

nSub <- 30
meas1 <- list()
meas2 <- list()
for (i in 1:nSub){
  meas1 <- lappend(meas1, rnorm(10))
  meas2 <- lappend(meas2, rnorm(10))
}
myList <- list(meas1 = meas1, meas2 = meas2)
```

Now, suppose I want a C++ function that for each subject, finds summation of measure1 and summation of measure 2 and then creates two new measurements based on these two summation. Finally the function should return these new measurements as a list.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List mySlowListFn(Rcpp::List myList, int nSub){
   arma::vec myMult(nSub);
   arma::vec myDiv(nSub);
   for (int i = 0; i < nSub; i++){
     arma::vec meas1_i = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(myList["meas1"])[i]);
     arma::vec meas2_i = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(myList["meas2"])[i]);
     myMult[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i)*arma::sum(meas2_i);
     myDiv[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i)/arma::sum(meas2_i);
   }
   return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("myMult") = myMult, 
                             Rcpp::Named("myDiv") = myDiv);
}
```

How can I make the function above faster? I'm particularly looking for ideas that keep the input and output lists in the code (since in my own program dealing with lists is inevitable), but with some tricks to reduce some overhead time. One thing that I thought of was:

```
 Rcpp::List mySlowListFn(const Rcpp::List& myList, int nSub)
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You are ending your question on an open conjecture which you could (and I dare add, _should_) test.

Comment: You could try a couple of tricks like using sugar functions or using the constructor of Armadillo vectors that do not make a copy. I'm not sure why lists would be slow.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, hi Dirk, I actually test it and I didn't see any difference between using a pointer or using myList itself which is very surprising! consider another function that calls the mySlowListFn above() . If we define mySlowListFn with a pointer argument to myList, how should I call this function inside my  callerFn ? can I directly use use myList as an argument or I should put it's address since it's assume to be a pointer? I'm trying to understand why using the pointer trick didn't make my code faster and I'm not sure if I use this trick correctly. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It makes no difference _because we interface to R via `SEXP` types_ which are already pointers. Adding `const &` is merely cosmetic at the C++ level.  You are shooting at the wrong target.

Comment: @Sameer, thanks sameer for your comment. What sugar functions you are particularly referring to? also regarding the armadillo vec idea, the fact is I'd like to keep lists in the function as is since in my original code I have to use List and I'd like to learn how to deal with lists to make my original function of interest faster.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I see. Is there any other idea that can make the code faster? The fact is in my original function of interest, my input list is a list that includes longitudinal measures for n subjects and there is no easy way to separate it into pieces so that I can avoid lists! So I have to find a way to deal with the issue.

Comment: If all you are doing is computing sums, why do copy into Armadillo containers just to create the sum?  Can't you sum over your lists?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, no in fact the example above is just a simplified example for my question. I could definitely write this function way more efficiently, but in my own function this is complicated that cannot be done by vectors or matrix in armadillo !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that copying semantics for lists have changed in recent versions of R (definitely in latest R-devel, not sure if it made it into R 3.1.0), whereby *shallow copies* of lists are made, and elements within are later copied if they are modified. There is a big chance that if you are running an older version of R, then its more expensive list copying semantics are getting in the way.

That said, here's how I would re-write your function for some extra speed, with a benchmark. `sourceCpp` it to compare on your own machine.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List mySlowListFn(Rcpp::List myList, int nSub){
   arma::vec myMult(nSub);
   arma::vec myDiv(nSub);
   for (int i = 0; i < nSub; i++){
     arma::vec meas1_i = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(myList["meas1"])[i]);
     arma::vec meas2_i = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(myList["meas2"])[i]);
     myMult[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i)*arma::sum(meas2_i);
     myDiv[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i)/arma::sum(meas2_i);
   }
   return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("myMult") = myMult, 
                             Rcpp::Named("myDiv") = myDiv);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List myFasterListFn(Rcpp::List myList, int nSub) {

  Rcpp::NumericVector myMult = Rcpp::no_init(nSub);
  Rcpp::NumericVector myDiv = Rcpp::no_init(nSub);

  Rcpp::List meas1 = myList["meas1"];
  Rcpp::List meas2 = myList["meas2"];

  for (int i = 0; i < nSub; i++) {

    arma::vec meas1_i( 
      REAL(VECTOR_ELT(meas1, i)), Rf_length(VECTOR_ELT(meas1, i)), false, true
    );

    arma::vec meas2_i(
      REAL(VECTOR_ELT(meas2, i)), Rf_length(VECTOR_ELT(meas2, i)), false, true
    );

    myMult[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i) * arma::sum(meas2_i);
    myDiv[i] = arma::sum(meas1_i) / arma::sum(meas2_i);
  }

  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("myMult") = myMult, 
    Rcpp::Named("myDiv") = myDiv
  );
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
lappend <- function(lst, ...){
  lst <- c(lst, list(...))
  return(lst)
}

nSub <- 30
n <- 10
meas1 <- list()
meas2 <- list()
for (i in 1:nSub){
  meas1 <- lappend(meas1, rnorm(n))
  meas2 <- lappend(meas2, rnorm(n))
}
myList <- list(meas1 = meas1, meas2 = meas2)
x1 <- mySlowListFn(myList, nSub)
x2 <- myFasterListFn(myList, nSub)
microbenchmark(
  mySlowListFn(myList, nSub),
  myFasterListFn(myList, nSub)
)
*/
```

gives me

```
> library(microbenchmark)

> lappend <- function(lst, ...){
+   lst <- c(lst, list(...))
+   return(lst)
+ }

> nSub <- 30

> n <- 10

> meas1 <- list()

> meas2 <- list()

> for (i in 1:nSub){
+   meas1 <- lappend(meas1, rnorm(n))
+   meas2 <- lappend(meas2, rnorm(n))
+ }

> myList <- list(meas1 = meas1, meas2 = meas2)

> x1 <- mySlowListFn(myList, nSub)

> x2 <- myFasterListFn(myList, nSub)

> microbenchmark(
+   mySlowListFn(myList, nSub),
+   myFasterListFn(myList, nSub)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                         expr    min      lq  median      uq    max neval
   mySlowListFn(myList, nSub) 14.772 15.4570 16.0715 16.7520 42.628   100
 myFasterListFn(myList, nSub)  4.502  5.0675  5.2470  5.8515 18.561   100
```

Future versions of `Rcpp` and `Rcpp11` will have the `ListOf<T>` class which will make it much easier to interact with lists where we know the inner type beforehand, after the proper semantics have been ironed out.

Comment: Very nice answer, as usual. Thank you, Kevin.

Comment: what would you do if you have a matrix inside those lists instead of vector? In other words, how would you modify this for matrices ( arma::vec meas2_i(
      REAL(VECTOR_ELT(meas2, i)), Rf_length(VECTOR_ELT(meas2, i)), false, true
    );)?

Comment: R matrices are just vectors with dimensions, so you could still use `REAL` to get the pointer, but then get the rows / columns with e.g. `Rf_nrows`, `Rf_ncols`. Or if you're trying to put a matrix into an `arma::vec`, you don't need to change anything (it will be filled 'column-wise')

Comment: It's actually the first time I see REAL and VECTOR_ELT. Would you elaborate more? Should we still use VECTOR_ELT()? Honestly, I have two challenges 1) understanding arma::vec meas1_i( 
      REAL(VECTOR_ELT(meas1, i)), Rf_length(VECTOR_ELT(meas1, i)), false, true
    ); and 2) how to get similar for matrix

Comment: `VECTOR_ELT` is a function from the base R API that extracts an element (`SEXP`) from an `R` list. Since `SEXP` is an opaque pointer, the data you get could be a vector, matrix, and so on. `REAL` is a macro that gets a pointer to the 'numeric' storage array of a 'numeric' vector. I recommend reading the first few chapters of [R-ints](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) as the solution I pose goes a bit outside of Rcpp.

Comment: Kevin, you have been always very very helpful. I truly appreciate it

Comment: @ Kevin Ushey I have a similar question regarding using lists as an input. Do you see any further improvement? My question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843167/using-list-as-an-input-in-c-code-and-calling-using-rcpplist-inputs-are-extrem/57893741?noredirect=1#comment105468938_57893741