# Using list as an input in C++ code and calling using Rcpp(List inputs are extremely slow)

Tags: c++, rstudio, rcpp

I am trying to use a list(R object) as an input for C++ function and later call it using Rcpp from R. This list contains large number of matrices. The code I provide is a toy example. I have a very complicated code that I have already written but very inefficient. In the following code, I want to know if there is an efficient way of extracting matrix from the list.

Following is the code that I have tried. It works but it also tells me that the subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector.I am using R studio to write this code. When I compile the code it works, but when I put mouse cursor in the editor I also see the red cross saying "subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector".

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List tt( 
    Rcpp::List&  ht,
    int n){
  List A(n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    arma::mat htt = ht[i];// this is where I see subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector
    arma::mat x = htt * htt.t();
    A[i] = x;//this is where I see subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector
  }
  List res(1);
  res[0] = A;//this is where I see subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector
  return(res);
}
```

Again, this is a toy example which could easily be done in R. I would like to get some idea on how this could be done efficiently. Suppose, I want every matrix of a list to be multiplied by it's transpose. Any help would be appreciated? Following is my actual problem.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List se_4a( 
     Rcpp::List& ht,
     const int& n, 
    const int& p,
    const int& pc,
    NumericMatrix& S1byS0_,
    NumericMatrix& S1byS0c_,
     NumericMatrix& za_,
     NumericMatrix& zb_,
     NumericMatrix& wd_,
     NumericMatrix& I_,
     NumericVector& S0c_,
     NumericVector& gammah_){

  List A(ht.length());

    arma::mat S1byS0hat(S1byS0_.begin(),S1byS0_.nrow(),S1byS0_.ncol(),false);
    arma::mat S1byS0hatc(S1byS0c_.begin(),S1byS0c_.nrow(),S1byS0c_.ncol(),false); 
    arma::mat z(za_.begin(),za_.nrow(),za_.ncol(),false);
    arma::mat zc(zb_.begin(),zb_.nrow(),zb_.ncol(),false);
    arma::mat wdM(wd_.begin(),wd_.nrow(),wd_.ncol(),false);
    arma::mat Ic(I_.begin(),I_.nrow(),I_.ncol(),false);
    arma::vec S0hatc(S0c_.begin(),S0c_.size(),false);
    arma::vec gammahat(gammah_.begin(),gammah_.size(),false);

   Rcpp::List q1hat(n);
   Rcpp::List q2hat(n);



  for(int i=0; i < n;++i){
    arma::mat q11hat(p,n);
    q11hat.zeros();
    arma::mat q21hat(p,n);
    q21hat.zeros();

    // arma::mat q11hat(q11hata.begin(),q11hata.nrow(),q11hata.ncol(),false);
    // arma::mat q21hat(q21hata.begin(),q21hata.nrow(),q21hata.ncol(),false);
    for(int u = 0;u < n; ++u){
      // arma::mat q(qa.begin(),qa.nrow(),qa.ncol(),false);
      // arma::mat qq(qqa.begin(),qqa.nrow(),qqa.ncol(),false);

      arma::mat q(p,1);
      q.zeros();
      arma::mat qq(p,1);
      qq.zeros();

      for(int j=0;j <n;++j){
        if(j < n){
          for(int k = j; k <n;++k){
               //NumericMatrix httt = as<NumericMatrix>(ht[k]);
               Rcpp::NumericMatrix htt_R = ht[k];
                arma::mat htt(htt_R.begin(), htt_R.rows(), htt_R.cols(), false, true);
                //arma::vec y = httt(_,j);
                arma::colvec y = htt.col(j);
               arma::rowvec yy = y.t() * Ic * (zc.row(i).t() - S1byS0hatc.col(u));
             double zz = yy(0,0);
              q += (z.row(j).t() - S1byS0hat.col(k)) *
                zz * wdM(j,k);
            if (u <= k){
              qq += (z.row(j).t() - S1byS0hat.col(k)) *
                exp(arma::as_scalar(gammahat.t()*zc.row(j).t()))*wdM(j,k) / (S0hatc(u)/n);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      q11hat.cols(u,u) = -1 * q;
      q21hat.cols(u,u) = -1 * qq;
    }
     q1hat[i] = q11hat/n;
     q2hat[i] = q21hat/n;
  }
    return List::create(Named("A")=q1hat,
                        Named("B")=q2hat);


}
```

Now, let's call the above function from R.

```
#Calling from R
ht <- list()
for(i in 1 : 100){
  ht[[i]] <-matrix(runif(10*100), 10, 100)
}
n <- 100
p <- 10
pc <- 10
S1byS0 <- matrix(rnorm(10*100),10,100)
S1byS0c <- S1byS0
za <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),100,10)
zb <- za
wd <- matrix(rnorm(100*100),100,100)
I <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
S0c <- c(rnorm(100))
gammah <- matrix(rnorm(10),1,10)

#Calling se_4a function

pp=bench::mark(se_4a(ht,n,p,pc, S1byS0,S1byS0c,za,zb,wd,I,S0c,gammah))
```

`bench::mark(se_4a(ht,n,p,pc, S1byS0,S1byS0c,za,zb,wd,I,S0c,gammah))`

```
# A tibble: 1 x 13
  expression                                                         min median `itr/sec`
  <bch:expr>                                                       <bch> <bch:>     <dbl>
1 se_4a(ht, n, p, pc, S1byS0, S1byS0c, za, zb, wd, I, S0c, gammah) 20.9s  20.9s    0.0479
# … with 9 more variables: mem_alloc <bch:byt>, `gc/sec` <dbl>, n_itr <int>, n_gc <dbl>,
#   total_time <bch:tm>, result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
Warning message:
Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
```

Using matrix as an argument instead of a list.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List se_4c( 
    const arma::mat& ht,
    const int& n, 
    const int& p,
    const int& pc,
    const arma::mat& S1byS0hat,
    const arma::mat& S1byS0hatc,
    const arma::mat& z,
    const arma::mat& zc,
    const arma::mat& wdM,
    const arma::mat& Ic,
    const arma::vec& S0hatc,
    const arma::vec& gammahat){

  Rcpp::List q1hat(n);
  Rcpp::List q2hat(n);

  arma::mat q11hat(p,n);
  arma::mat q21hat(p,n);
  arma::mat q(p,1);
  arma::mat qq(p,1);

   std::vector<arma::mat> htt_vec(n);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  //   Rcpp::NumericMatrix htt_R = ht[i];
  //   arma::mat htt(htt_R.begin(), htt_R.rows(), htt_R.cols(), false, true);
  //   htt_vec[i] = htt;
  htt_vec[i] = ht.rows(i,i+(p-1));
   }



  for(int i=0; i < n;++i){
    for(int u = 0;u < n; ++u){

      q.zeros();
      qq.zeros();

      arma::mat bar = Ic * (zc.row(i).t() - S1byS0hatc.col(u));

      for(int j=0;j <n;++j){
        if(j < n){
          double foo = exp(arma::as_scalar(gammahat.t()*zc.row(j).t())) / (S0hatc(u)/n);
          for(int k = j; k <n;++k){
            //arma::mat htt_vec = ht.rows(k,k+(p-1));
            arma::colvec y = htt_vec[k].col(j);
            arma::rowvec yy = y.t() * bar;
            double zz = yy(0,0);
            arma::mat baz = (z.row(j).t() - S1byS0hat.col(k)) * wdM(j,k);
            q +=  zz * baz;
            if (u <= k){
              qq += foo * baz;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      q11hat.col(u) = -q;
      q21hat.col(u) = -qq;
    }
    q1hat[i] = q11hat/n;
    q2hat[i] = q21hat/n;
  }
  return List::create(Named("A")=q1hat,
                      Named("B")=q2hat);


}
```

Following is the simple code that takes about 4 secs. Expected it to faster.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test( 
    List& ht,
    const int& n,
    const int& p){

  Rcpp::List q1hat(n);
  Rcpp::List q2hat(n);



  for(int i=0; i < n;++i){
    arma::mat q11hat(p,n);
    q11hat.zeros();
    arma::mat q21hat(p,n);
    q21hat.zeros();
    for(int u = 0;u < n; ++u){
      arma::mat q(p,1);
      q.zeros();
      arma::mat qq(p,1);
      qq.zeros();

      for(int j=0;j <n;++j){
        if(j < ht.length()){
          for(int k = j; k <n;++k){
            Rcpp::NumericMatrix htt_R = ht[k];
            arma::mat htt(htt_R.begin(), htt_R.rows(), htt_R.cols(), false, true);

          }
        }
      }
      q11hat.cols(u,u) = -1 * q;
      q21hat.cols(u,u) = -1 * qq;
    }
    q1hat[i] = q11hat/n;
    q2hat[i] = q21hat/n;
  }
  return List::create(Named("A")=q1hat,
                      Named("B")=q2hat);
}
```

The formula that I am trying to implement is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Which version of RStudio do you use? These messages have become better with version 1.2. However, you should be fine as long as the compiler does not produce warnings (when called with `-Wall`).

Comment: I use version 3.6.1. The complier does not give any error. I am writing my other complicated code in a similar fashion where it takes about 40 seconds to get the result. I not only have list as an input, but matrices and vectors are also input. For example, I use arma::mat or arma::rowvec etc. Can the above code be improved?

Comment: @RalfStubner: I am not sure how to call with _Wall. Could you please give an example?

Comment: 3.6.1 would be the R version, not the RStudio version. I am using RStudio 1.2.1572 on Debian testing, and I see no such messages. Concerning `-Wall`: You can set such options in `~/.R/Makevars`. There should be multiple messages on this site about that.

Comment: Concerning improvements: `n` seems unnecessary, since an `Rcpp::List` knows its length. I am not sure why you use `res` as a second level of `Rcpp::List`. Other then that it is diffcult to give suggestions based on this example.

Comment: @RalfStubner: I am trying to output A which is a list. Do you mean that I don't need to introduce res as a List.

Comment: Exactly. Since `A` is a list, you could also just use `return A;`.

Comment: @RalfStubner: In my actual code, I need to return two lists. Above example was just a toy example for illustration.

Comment: @RalfStubner: My main concern with the code that I am actually writing is that whenever I compute arma::mat htt = ht[i]; it is very slow. I would like some idea on how, I can make this part more efficient.

Comment: Is the performance your main concern? You could assign to a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` first and then use the advanced constructors to create an `arma::mat` without copying the data, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552149/rcpp-sugar-commands-in-armadillo/51578960#51578960

Comment: @RalfStubner: Yes, performance is my main concern. So what you are saying is that to use all the inputs as Rcpp objects and convert to armadillo objects. Actually, I tried this way too, but performance did not improve. I am not sure if I used the advanced constructors correctly or not.

Comment: @RalfStubner: Okay, I first assigned Rcpp object and then used advanced constructors. The computing time reduced to about 22 secs from 40 seconds. That is quite a improvement. I think the majority of computing time is taken when I try to extract matrix from a list. That is Rcpp::NumericMatrix htt=ht[i];
            arma::mat httt(htt.begin(),httt.nrow(),htt.ncol(),false); Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @RalfStubner: So basically I have a input ht, then I need to extract each element(matrix) of a list ht. Then for each matrix for each list I need to extract a column. I think this is where I am losing efficiency. So my input list ht is a Rcpp object, then I extract matrix from that list using NumericMatrix, then I extract column from that matrix using arma::vec. Is this causing the program to be slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several comments:

- RcppArmadillo can make use of Armadillo's advanced constructors directly for function arguments. I am not sure about the precise condition, but `const` references get treated like this.
- Extracting a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` from a `Rcpp::List` seems to be costly. It therefore makes sense to process the matrices once in the beginning.
- Several parts of your calculations where independent of the inner loop variables. It makes sense to calculate them once before the loop (see `foo`, `bar` and `baz` below).
- I have also done some clean-up.

Alternative function:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List se_4b( 
        Rcpp::List& ht,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const int& pc,
        const arma::mat& S1byS0hat,
        const arma::mat& S1byS0hatc,
        const arma::mat& z,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::mat& wdM,
        const arma::mat& Ic,
        const arma::vec& S0hatc,
        const arma::vec& gammahat){

    Rcpp::List q1hat(n);
    Rcpp::List q2hat(n);

    arma::mat q11hat(p,n);
    arma::mat q21hat(p,n);
    arma::mat q(p,1);
    arma::mat qq(p,1);

    std::vector<arma::mat> htt_vec(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix htt_R = ht[i];
        arma::mat htt(htt_R.begin(), htt_R.rows(), htt_R.cols(), false, true);
        htt_vec[i] = htt;        
    }

    for(int i=0; i < n;++i){
        for(int u = 0;u < n; ++u){

            q.zeros();
            qq.zeros();

            arma::mat bar = Ic * (zc.row(i).t() - S1byS0hatc.col(u));

            for(int j=0;j <n;++j){
                if(j < n){
                    double foo = exp(arma::as_scalar(gammahat.t()*zc.row(j).t())) / (S0hatc(u)/n);
                    for(int k = j; k <n;++k){
                        arma::colvec y = htt_vec[k].col(j);
                        arma::rowvec yy = y.t() * bar;
                        double zz = yy(0,0);
                        arma::mat baz = (z.row(j).t() - S1byS0hat.col(k)) * wdM(j,k);
                        q +=  zz * baz;
                        if (u <= k){
                            qq += foo * baz;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            q11hat.col(u) = -q;
            q21hat.col(u) = -qq;
        }
        q1hat[i] = q11hat/n;
        q2hat[i] = q21hat/n;
    }
    return List::create(Named("A")=q1hat,
                        Named("B")=q2hat);


}
```

Benchmark result comparing with your function:

```
> bench::mark(se_4a = se_4a(ht,n,p,pc, S1byS0,S1byS0c,za,zb,wd,I,S0c,gammah),
+             se_4b = se_4b(ht,n,p,pc, S1by .... [TRUNCATED] 
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
  <bch:expr> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 se_4a      21.97s 21.97s    0.0455    1.54MB     7.97     1   175     21.97s <list…
2 se_4b       4.84s  4.84s    0.206     1.54MB     0        1     0      4.84s <list…
# … with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an example. I followed your suggestion. However, still takes about 13 seconds. I have added my actual code in the problem. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: @Hello What sort of input do you have? Random data with the right structure would be fine.

Comment: ht is a list with matrices, and all others are as specified in the code. We can think of these all as double.n, p and pc are integers.

Comment: Please see the simple code in the question. That also takes about 4 secs. I expected it to run much faster. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hello Please show some sample R code including *concrete* values for the function arguments. Besides that, you are doing a lot of memory allocation and initialization within deeply nested loops.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for going step by step in this example with me.  Please the R code in the question. I have shown a sample R code that includes the concrete values for the function arguments. As you mentioned that memory allocation and initialization is my concern here. Hopefully, you can provide some insights that I am missing.

Comment: @Hello Please see the reworked answer. There were quite a few things in your code you did more then once.

Comment: Thank you very much. Okay, instead of using list as an argument, maybe I can rbind all the matrices inside a list and use that big matrix as an argument write the code accordingly. Do you think that can improve efficiency?

Comment: Well I tried using matrix as an argument however it took about 5 seconds. Please see the function se_4c. So is this the best that we can do with this function?

Comment: @Hello It might be possible to use a different algorithm, but I don't see anything like this at the moment.

Comment: Okay. Can we improve the function se_4c?

Comment: @Hello As I said, I don't see any obvious improvements right now.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for you answers and explanation.

Comment: I observed that if I changed by n to 500 then it takes very very long time. I think it is better to use a different algorithm as Ralf Stubner suggested.

Comment: When n= 500, it took about 21 minutes. Definitely need a different algorithm. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I am still looking for ideas to improve this algorithm.

Comment: @Hello The current algorithm is O(n^4), making it impractical for longer lists. I don’t see any obvious improvements from the code alone. I have not tried to reverse engineering the intent of the algorithm.

Comment: So even if I use matrix instead of list, then it is still slow. Rcpp is lacking efficiency for this type of issue then. Am I correct?

Comment: @Hello This is not about Rcpp (or any other tool) but about algorithmic complexity. Just do the math: How often is the most inner loop executed for n = 100? And How often for n = 200? If a better algorithm is found, this will help regardless of the tools used, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109654/8416610. In that case it was quite easy to extract the intention from the initial algorithm, allowing me to propose a faster algorithm. I do not understand the intention in your case.

Comment: Okay. So even if this code was written in C then the performance  would not have improved. My impression was if an algorithm is written in C, then it is always efficient provided that I use pointer. My goal is to develop R package but i don't think it would be accepted with this efficiency.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner: I have posted a new question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417845/returning-bunch-of-matrices-using-rcpp-in-c-in-an-efficient-way-using-a-list. Could you please help me when you have a chance?

Comment: @ Ralf Can the function se_4b that you suggested above be improved? For n=1600, it takes about half a minute.

Comment: @Hello I do not see any possibilities for radical improvement. THese might still exist, I just don't know or understand the math here.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner: Please see the formula that I am trying to implement. The calculation of h part was already done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417845/returning-bunch-of-matrices-using-rcpp-in-c-in-an-efficient-way-using-a-list

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner: Any suggestions on how to improve this code. I have also provided the formula that I am trying to implement.

Comment: @Hello I have seen the formula, but I haven't had enough time to look at it closely.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner: Sure. Thanks.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hello Unfortunately no.