# Returning bunch of matrices using RCPP in C++ in an efficient way using a list

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to return a bunch of matrices using RCPP. My code below is extremely inefficient. I would like to know if the following code can be efficient.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List hello( 
    const arma::rowvec& g,
    const int& n, 
    const int& p,
    const arma::mat& S,
    const arma::mat& zc,
    const arma::rowvec& dl){
  Rcpp::List ht(n);

  for(int t=0; t < n;++t){

    arma::mat hhat(p,n);
    hhat.fill(0.0);
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
      arma::mat h(p,1);
      h.fill(0.0);
      if (t > i){
        for(int u=i;u <= t; ++u){
          arma::rowvec zr = zc.rows(i,i);
          h += exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zr.t())) * (zr.t() - S.cols(u,u))*dl(u);
        }
      }
      hhat.cols(i,i) = h;
    }
    ht[t] = hhat;
  }

  // Specify list length
  Rcpp::List res(1);
  res[0] = ht;

  return(res);
}
```

Here is the example.

```
g=c(1,2.1,3.1)
n=1600
p=3
S = matrix(rnorm(4800),nrow=3,ncol=1600)
dl=runif(1600)
z=matrix(runif(4800),nrow=1600,ncol=3)
ptm=proc.time();kkk= hello(g=g,n=n,p=p,S = S,zc=z,dl = dl);proc.time()-ptm;
 user  system elapsed 
  31.25    0.00   31.30
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Following the updated code. Initially I was returning list of a list. Now it returns a list. This reduces the computing time by 10 seconds. I hope this code can be improved further.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List hello( 
    const arma::rowvec& g,
    const int& n, 
    const int& p,
    const arma::mat& S,
    const arma::mat& zc,
    const arma::rowvec& dl){
  Rcpp::List ht(n);


  for(int t=0; t < n;++t){

    arma::mat hhat(p,n);
    hhat.zeros();
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
      arma::mat h(p,1);
      // h.fill(0.0);
      h.zeros();
      if (t > i){
        for(int u=i;u <= t; ++u){
          //arma::rowvec zr = zc.rows(i,i);
          h += exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(u))*dl(u);
        }
      }
      hhat.col(i) = h;
    }
    ht[t] = hhat;
  }

  // Specify list length
  // Rcpp::List res(1);
  // res[0] = ht;

  return(ht);
}
```

The formula that I am trying to implement is given below.[image]

Comment: Are you making unnecessary copies? (try to profile it). Could you rewrite this as matrix operations instead of loops?

Comment: Okay. What I found was I was returning list of list. But I only return a list now which reduces the computing time by 10 seconds.

Comment: With your new code I get a run-time error `as_scalar(): incompatible dimensions`. With your original code I looked at the scaling for `n = 400, 800, 1600`. I found roughly a factor of 2^3 for each step. It might be possible to formulate this more efficiently, but this is (again) difficult without knowing the intend of the computation.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner Okay I just fixed my code. My goal is to get matrix of p by n and save it in a list. So at the end i should have list of n matrices each of size p by n.

Comment: @ Hello, I think @RalfStubner 's point was more the intent of the computation behind each p by n matrix, not just that you wanted to create a list of matrices of that size. If we knew what mathematical problem you were trying to solve, or what routine/computation you were trying to implement, it would be *much* easier to provide helpful advice. The biggest potential for speedup here is likely with reference to a better implementation of the math, not just finding some inefficient syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my other answer I looked at the efficiency of returning data and at simple optimizations. Here I want to look at something different: Optimization of the algorithm.

You want to compute `hhat(i, t)` for `0 <= i, t < n` and `i < t`. Looking at your formula we see that the dependency of `hhat` on `i` and `t` is very different. In particular, `hhat(i, t + 1)` can be written as `hhat(i, t) + something`. Right now your outer loop is over `t` and you are recomputing all these intermediate values. By switching the loop order, it is easy to do each such computation only once, bringing the algorithm down to a two nested loops. This means you have to generate the resulting matrices separately. And since you cannot store an `arma::mat` inside a `Rcpp::List`, I need an additional `std::vector` for storage:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List hello( 
        const arma::rowvec& g,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const arma::mat& S,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::rowvec& dl){

    std::vector<arma::mat> foo(n);
    for(int t=0; t < n;++t){
        arma::mat hhat(p,n);
        hhat.zeros();
        foo[t] = hhat;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
        arma::mat h = exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(i))*dl(i);
        for(int t=i+1; t < n;++t){
            h += exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(t))*dl(t);
            foo[t].col(i) = h;
        }
    }

    Rcpp::List ht(n);
    for(int t=0; t < n;++t){
        ht[t] = foo[t];
    }

    return(ht);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List hello_orig( 
        const arma::rowvec& g,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const arma::mat& S,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::rowvec& dl){
    Rcpp::List ht(n);


    for(int t=0; t < n;++t){

        arma::mat hhat(p,n);
        hhat.zeros();
        for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
            arma::mat h(p,1);
            h.zeros();
            if (t > i){
                for(int u=i;u <= t; ++u){
                    h += exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(u))*dl(u);
                }
            }
            hhat.col(i) = h;
        }
        ht[t] = hhat;
    }

    return(ht);
}

/***R
g=c(1,2.1,3.1)
n=1600
p=3
S = matrix(rnorm(p*n),nrow=p,ncol=n)
dl=runif(n)
z=matrix(runif(p*n),nrow=n,ncol=p)
bench::mark(hello_orig(g=g,n=n,p=p,S = S,zc=z,dl = dl),
            hello(g=g,n=n,p=p,S = S,zc=z,dl = dl))
*/
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression                                                 min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>                                              <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 hello_orig(g = g, n = n, p = p, S = S, zc = z, dl = dl)  14.2s  14.2s    0.0703    58.7MB
2 hello(g = g, n = n, p = p, S = S, zc = z, dl = dl)      53.9ms 85.9ms   11.1       58.7MB
# … with 8 more variables: `gc/sec` <dbl>, n_itr <int>, n_gc <dbl>, total_time <bch:tm>,
#   result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

More than a factor 100 faster!

You can get cleaner (and maybe even a bit faster code) by floowing @coatless' suggestions in the comments to use an `arma::cube`. The most compact form will give you a different return structure, though. Instead of a list of `p x n` you will get a `p x n x n` array:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube coatless( 
        const arma::rowvec& g,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const arma::mat& S,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::rowvec& dl){

    arma::cube ht(p, n, n);
    ht.zeros();

    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
        arma::mat h = exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(i))*dl(i);
        for(int t=i+1; t < n;++t){
            h += exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * (zc.row(i).t() - S.col(t))*dl(t);
            ht.slice(t).col(i) = h;
        }
    }

    return(ht);
}
```

Comment: Well done Ralf! This is what we were talking about in the comments @Hello -- optimizations on the math side almost always **far** outstrip simple code optimizations.

Comment: @ Ralf Wow. Thank you very much. Yes you are right that this code is 100 times factor. So on this line std::vector<arma::mat> foo(n), is foo a list of size n? I know that we are storing p by n matrix for each t.

Comment: @Hello `foo` is a vector of size `n`. I am using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list` since I want random access to list members. For the `std::vector` I know that it contains `arma::mat` objects. Their size is only determined via the code.

Comment: @ Ralf Great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RalfStubner probably should use a cube structure here: 
`arma::cube foo = cube(p, n, n);  foo.zeros()`. Then, switch over to accessing per slice: `foo.slice(i).col(i);`.

Comment: @coatless thanks for the suggestion, that makes the code quite a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title makes one think you see the problem in returning the data to R. Rest assured that this is not an issue. You can easily check this by calling a function that returns matrices of zeros in the required size:

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List minimal( 
        const arma::rowvec& g,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const arma::mat& S,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::rowvec& dl){
    Rcpp::List ht(n);

    for(int t=0; t < n;++t){

        arma::mat hhat(p,n);
        hhat.zeros();
        ht[t] = hhat;
    }

    return(ht);
}
```

On my system this function takes about 0.01 s with your input data. In other words, your real function spends most of its time on computing the actual results.

As for optimizing that part, it would be helpful if you could provide an idea of what you are trying to implement, e.g. with the help of mathematical formulas. As it stands, I can only do some simple changes:

- In the `i` loop you only do something for `t > i`. Therefore it is sufficient to let the loop run till `i < t`.
- The `u` loop can be formulated as a matrix-vector product, for which efficient implementations exist.

With changes like this I end up with

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List hello( 
        const arma::rowvec& g,
        const int& n, 
        const int& p,
        const arma::mat& S,
        const arma::mat& zc,
        const arma::rowvec& dl){
    Rcpp::List ht(n);

    for(int t=0; t < n;++t){

        arma::mat hhat(p,n);
        hhat.zeros();
        for(int i = 0;i < t; ++i){
            arma::mat Sit = S.cols(i,t);
            hhat.col(i) = - exp(arma::as_scalar(g*zc.row(i).t())) * 
                (Sit.each_col() - zc.row(i).t()) * dl.subvec(i,t).t();
        }
        ht[t] = hhat;
    }

    return(ht);
}
```

On my system this is about a factor of two faster than your code. It might well be possible to get even faster, though.

Comment: @ Ralf Stubner I have added an image of the formula that I am trying to code. In the formula, t goes from t_1 to t_n and i goes from 1 to n. The second term inside a curly bracket is S in my example.